# Access 2016 tab control - tabs still clickable when hidden

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I have a tab control object on my Access form and have changed the style to none so that the tabs are not visible, however when I click on where the tabs would be it still changes the pages like as if they were there.

Is this normal behaviour and is there any way to prevent the tabs from being able to be clicked?

Comment: Apparently it is normal. I have never used this setting. Why are you? I have used Visible property.

Comment: The visible property of the tab control itself? That makes all of the objects on it invisible too?

Comment: Ah I understand now, you mean the visible property of the individual pages. I didn't realise that was the correct way to do it. Thanks

Comment: always thought it would disable the page navigation by setting the `style` property to `none` as well, but it doesn't!  setting only one specific page `Visible=True` ensures the user won't be able to switch pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design.  You could take advantage of this setting to display images where the tabs would otherwise be so that it appears to the user that they are clicking on the image to change tabs.

As you've already figured out, you should set the Visible property to False if you want the tab to be both hidden and disabled.